# Pylons: nosetests, specify location of development.ini?

Tags: unit-testing, pylons, nosetests

I'm running `nosetests` on a remote server.

On my local server my `test.ini` and `development.ini` files are in the same directory. On my remote server, they are not.

If I try to run just

```
nosetests
```

on the remote server, I get:

```
IOError: File '/foo/bar/development.ini' not found
```

Is there an option to specify the location of `development.ini` (as opposed to `test.ini`, for which I think you could use `--config=`) in on the command line? I don't want to edit `setup.cfg` if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nosetests version installed into you virtualenv of the Pylons installation should have a nose plugin that allows you to specify a `--with-pylons` parameter pointing to your `development.ini`.

So try

```
$ nosetests --with-pylons=<your path>/development.ini
```

on the server.